# how to find necessary geoserver/geotools maven dependencies for a class?

Tags: geoserver, geotools, wps, maven

I am trying to create a Web Processing Service with GeoServer. I used `maven` following opengeo instructions, and I get an eclipse project with a `pom.xml` file with dependencies like the following:

```
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
     <artifactId>gt-process</artifactId>
     <version>12-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
     <artifactId>gt-geometry</artifactId>
     <version>12-SNAPSHOT</version>
   </dependency>
   ...
 </dependencies>
```

Now there is only a limited set of dependencies in the example. If I add other classes, I often get errors about class not being resolved. For example,

```
import org.geoserver.wps.WPSStorageCleaner;
```

or

```
import org.geotools.gce.geotiff.GeoTiffReader;
```

My question is, ***in general***, where/how can I find out the correct values of `<groupId>, <artifactId> etc.`  for classes like above? Is there a central registry for this kind of info?

I need to do this in maven, and not by otherwise fiddling with eclipse settings and the like.
The closest thing I can find is at https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.geoserver
However, the versions there are at 1.x, and I don't know how to use the values there.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up trying to find a maven repository to resolve the classes that geoserver's example POM file shows as well as a general way find either geotools or geoserver's correct current maven repository information when I ran into monstrosities such as [this](http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/geoserver/extension/) because I did not want to download / develop against all of geoserver's sources.

I ended up downloading the extension zip archive I wanted to develop against, the one whose contents you need to install into geoserver's `webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib` directory to get geoserver to actually enable the extension.

Then, using this [Can I add jars to maven 2 build classpath without installing them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them) solution, I put the extension jar files, e.g., `gs-wps-core-2.7.0.jar`, into a project `lib` directory and named it `org.geoserver.extension.gs-wps-core-2.7.0.jar`. Then I ran the `install-to-project-repo.py` script referenced in that answer to create the necessary project repo directory structure and the maven repository and dependency definitions:

```
<repository>
    <id>project</id>
    <url>file://${project.basedir}/repo</url>
</repository>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.geoserver.extension</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-wps-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

No more maven complaints. Not an answer to the original question but maybe this will provide a pragmatic solution.

Comment: Jesus Christ man! I can't believe there is no way to discover it. Geotools maven support is very poor. I'm getting some examples around and it's a nightmare to find the correct dependencies to put in my POM file.

Comment: I am not Him and I have since moved on from this issue. But one way to discover all the hidden dependencies, as well as dependencies that are actually unused, is with the [Maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/). I find the `mvn dependency:tree` analysis gives me the details that I am looking for. (Note the -Dverbose option.)

Comment: I don't know how this can solve the problem. Lets say we have a package import `org.geotools.data.ows.CRSEnvelope` in our class. How can I find the correct `artifactId`? Or worst just a `WebMapServer wms = new WebMapServer(url)` without any package information?

Answer (score 0):

For GeoTools modules you could try browsing the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/) which contains a list of the [main modules](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/index.html) and the [extensions](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

For now I'm playing in this site https://www.versioneye.com/search?lang=%2C&q=ows&g=org.geotools and do my best to find out